# Pentaho Abort option is not working

Tags: pentaho, abort

I have designed abort mechanism in one of our pentaho Jobs. I was testing it functionality in two different cases. (Triggering transformation using shell script step  eg:pan.sh)

case1: Given wrong table name in table input step and triggered the job. Job aborted successfully.

case2: writing a file to HDFS(Hive), and given a wrong path. Job log shows Error but Pentaho job is ended successfully. Abort job is not working.

Any clue, Please help me.

Regards
Kp.

Answer (score 0):

That's true. Pentaho did exactly what you asked: abort. So it is not an Error. Although many user did complain it should be.

This is because other users did complain that in a chain of Job, the error on one job must not prevent the rest of the chain to proceed. In facts in a chain of jobs, you control the flow by telling if an arrow is to be followed in case of success or in case of error (right-click / Evaluation).

If you control your flow from the shell or from a crontab, you can check the status of the linux command `kitchen.sh` which is 0 if the process ran without problem or 1 if an error occurred. Check tough I am still on Pentaho 7.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Obviously $? will be 0 since the Job has ended with Success status even there were errors. so how to control here and make the job aborted.  any idea??

Comment: 1) Use the logging system [right-click anywhere, Preferences Logging, Transformation, give a connection and a table name]. The status of the guilty transformation/job will be recorded in that table, which can be checked with SQL.

Comment: 2) Explicitly define a status and save it somewhere (file/table/environment variable) and check this from the script.

Comment: yeah, that is the only solution now we have. for time being just reading the log, in case of any errors then abort it. :)